# Edit list of Favorite apps in Applications menu in Gnome Classic Centos7?

Tags: dconf, gnome-classic, applications-database

I'm running a CentOS 7 + GNOME **Classic** (Gnome 3 for some unknown reason, crashes) and I'm trying to customize the "Favorites" sub-menu, under the main "Applications" menu.

Apparently I should use `dconf` or alternatively `gsettings`. I've tried the following but no response from the system.

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
$
```

Here's the content of `~/.config/dconf/user` file, which I have edited to suit my needs:

```
$ cat .config/dconf/user 
# Set gedit, terminal and nautilus as default favorites
[org/gnome/shell]
favorite-apps = ['gedit.desktop', 'terminator.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop']
$
```

...and the `/etc/dconf/profile/user` file:

```
$ cat /etc/dconf/profile/user 
user-db:user
system-db:local
system-db:site
system-db:distro
$
```

What am I missing here? Can someone please point me in the right direction?